# cant spot nested for loop error

Tags: c++, sorting

Trying to sort county population within states. sorting by number only is easy, its trying to match the name to the sorted population that is causing me grief. I'm pretty sure my problem is in my last nested for loop in my counties sorted by pop function.

```
struct county { 
   string name;  //name of county 
   string *city;  // array of city names in county 
   int cities;  //number of cities in county 
   int population;  //total population of county 
   float avg_income;  //avg household income 
   float avg_house;  //avg household price 
}; 
struct state { 
  string name;  //name of state 
  struct county *c;  //array of counties 
  int counties;  //number of counties in state 
  int population;  //total population of state 
 };


void counties_sorted_by_pop(state * states_array, int num_states){
        vector<int> counties;
        int num_counties_total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < num_states; i++){
                        num_counties_total += states_array[i].counties;
        }
        cout << "COUNTIES SORTED BY POPULATION\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < num_states; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < states_array[i].counties; j++){
                        counties.push_back(states_array[i].c[j].population);
                }
        }
        sort(counties.begin(), counties.end());
        for(int i = 0; i < num_counties_total; i++){
                cout << counties[i] << endl;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < num_states; i++){
                cout << "in first loop\n";
                for(int j = 0; j < states_array[i].counties; j++){
                        if(counties[j] == states_array[i].c[j].population){
                                cout << states_array[i].c[j].name << endl;
                        }
                }
        }
        cout << endl;
}
```

and here is my output that i get

COUNTIES SORTED BY POPULATION

50000
53000
65000
65000
75000
75000
80000
80000
in first loop
in first loop
in first loop
in first loop

the error im running into is matching the correct county name to the sorted population vector and then printing it. Can anyone spot my error?

Comment: "Here is some code.  What is wrong with it?"  This is not a real question.   You haven't even told us what the symptoms are.

Comment: @JohnZwinck you are absolutely correct, ive edited my post, how is it now?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to achieve is to print out names of counties sorted by their population.

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_states; i++) {
  cout << "in first loop\n";
  for(int j = 0; j < states_array[i].counties; j++) {
    if(counties[] == states_array[i].c[j].population) {
      cout << states_array[i].c[j].name << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

First problem is in `if(counties[] == states_array[i].c[j].population)`. You are not indexing any element in counties (`counties[]`). Therefore you can't compare this with int value you get from `states_array[i].c[j].population`. 
To fix this you have to enwrap the last loop in one more loop iterating over sorted counties:

```
for(int k = 0; k < num_counties_total; k++) {
  for(int i = 0; i < num_states; i++) {
    cout << "in first loop\n";
    for(int j = 0; j < states_array[i].counties; j++) {
      if(counties[k] == states_array[i].c[j].population) {
        cout << states_array[i].c[j].name << endl;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Even though this idea is correct (only if each county has different population), this approach is very slow (sorting has a complexity of O(nlogn) + matching counties by population has complexity O(n^2), where n is the total number of counties). To make it faster you can make new `vector<county>`. Put all counties from all the states into this vector, sort it with respect to their population and print the names of sorted counties. To sort with respect to the population you have to use your own compare function. You can find more here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Edit: 
To have a correct program even in the case when two counties have the same population you should put all counties in the vector of counties and sort them.

```
bool my_cmp(county a, county b) {
  return a.population < b.population;
}

void counties_sorted_by_pop(state * states_array, int num_states) {
  vector<county> counties;
  for(int i = 0; i < num_states; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < states_array[i].counties; j++){
      //put all the counties to the vector<county>
      counties.push_back(states_array[i].c[j]);
    }
  }

  //sort counties with custom compare function
  sort(counties.begin(), counties.end(), my_cmp);

  //print sorted vector
  for(int i = 0; i < counties.size(); i++) {
    cout << counties[i].name << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i wouldn't have guessed i needed 3 for loops.

Comment: ok your help at least got it to print the names in order, only problem is when two counties have the same population it prints out each county twice. here is what i mean. 
COUNTIES SORTED BY POPULATION
50000                                                                                                
53000
65000
65000
75000
75000
80000
80000
Pickens: 50000
Benton: 53000
Yolo: 65000
Yoda: 65000
Yolo: 65000
Yoda: 65000
Orange: 75000
Jackson: 75000
Orange: 75000
Jackson: 75000
Lane: 80000
Anderson: 80000
Lane: 80000
Anderson: 80000

Comment: It's because population itself is not enough to distinguish between counties with the same population (obviously). Then the solution would be putting all the counties into `vector<county>` instead of only storing population in `vector<int>` and then sorting this vector of counties with custom compare function with respect to their population. I will edit my answer to show how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly but I think [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) can help you here, Something like this :

```
#include <map>

void counties_sorted_by_pop(state * states_array, int num_states)
{
    multimap<int, string> sorted_counties_name;

    int num_counties_total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_states; i++)
    {
        num_counties_total += states_array[i].counties;
    }
    cout << "COUNTIES SORTED BY POPULATION\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < num_states; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < states_array[i].counties; j++)
        {
            sorted_counties_name.insert(std::pair<int, string>(states_array[i].c[j].population, states_array[i].c[j].name));
        }
    }

    for(auto iter = sorted_counties_name.begin(); iter != sorted_counties_name.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << iter->first << "   " << iter->second << endl;
    }
}
```

I think this way your complexity would be `O(nlog n)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you sort `counties` independently from `states_array` the sequence of both containers won't match. One possibility to solve is using

```
std::map<std::string, int> countyNamePopulation
```

sort that with `std::sort` and output this within a loop

```
for (const auto& e : countyNamePopulation)
{
    std::cout << "County name: " << e.first << ", Population: " << e.second;
}
```

Next time please add a main function with example domain code (i.e. state and county objects) so people who would like to help can debug right away. Furthermore an explanation to the task is required. And welcome to SO!